# Laravel events firing multiple times, should only be firining once

Tags: php, laravel, events

I have a model called Project, that has some model events setup like this,

```
class Project extends Eloquent {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // new project created
        static::created(function($project)
        {
             // create the data informing the client to pull the new project information
             $pullData = [
                'id' => $project->id,
                'item' => 'project',
                'type' => 'created',
                'interface' => '/project/basic/'.$project->id
            ];
            foreach($project->organisation->users as $user) {
                if ($user->id != $project->user_id)
                    Pusherer::trigger('private-user'.$user->id, 'project:createdPull', $pullData);
                }
            }

            Event::subscribe(new ProjectEventHandler);
            Event::fire('project.create', array($project));

            Event::fire('project.create', array($project));
            Event::forget('project.create');


            Event::subscribe(new OrganisationEventHandler);
            Event::fire('organisation.project.add', array($project,  $project->organisation, $project->user));
            Event::forget('organisation.project.add');
    });
}
```

I create a project like this,

```
    $project = new Project;
    $project->name = $this->first_name . "'s example project";
    $project->slug = Stringhelpers::_uriHash( time() . $project->name );
    $project->uri_hash = Stringhelpers::_slugify($project->name);
    $project->total_cost = "1000.00";
    $project->start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $project->finish_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month'));
    //$project->owner_id = $this->id;
    $project->client_id = $client->id;
    $project->status = 2;
    $project->user_id = $this->id;
    $project->organisation_id = $organisation->id;
    $project->archived_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    //$project->socketId = $this->socketId;

    //Add the created user to the project as a just watcher.
    //$project->flushEventListeners();

    if($project->save()) {
        $project->users()->attach(array($this->id => array('role' => 3, 'last_tab' => 'home')));
    }
```

To my mind this this should fire the created event on the model once, and each of the subscribed events once, but it is firining the events, or the created event 3 times, would there be reason for this?

======= Further Details ======

I am saving multiple models in my process, I have noticed that I get multiple events firing when there have been a previous save, so I do the following, I get too Item events,

```
$project = new Project;
    $project->name = $this->first_name . "'s example project";
    $project->slug = Stringhelpers::_uriHash( time() . $project->name );
    $project->uri_hash = Stringhelpers::_slugify($project->name);
    $project->total_cost = "1000.00";
    $project->start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $project->finish_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month'));
    //$project->owner_id = $this->id;
    $project->client_id = $client->id;
    $project->status = 2;
    $project->user_id = $this->id;
    $project->organisation_id = $organisation->id;
    $project->archived_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    //$project->socketId = $this->socketId;

    //Add the created user to the project as a just watcher.
    //$project->flushEventListeners();

    if($project->save()) {
        $project->users()->attach(array($this->id => array('role' => 3, 'last_tab' => 'home')));
    }

$item = new Item;
    $item->name = $this->first_name . "'s example item";
    $item->percentage_complete = 0;
    $item->project_id = $project->id;
    $item->workflow_id = 0;
    $item->user_id = $this->id;
    $item->start_date = $project->start_date;
    $item->finish_date = $project->finish_date;
    //$item->socketId = $this->socketId;
    //$item->flushEventListeners();
    $item->save();
```

my Item model looks like this,

```
public class Item extends Eloquent {

public static function boot() { 

        parent::boot();

        // new item created 
        static::created(function($item) {
            // fire project pusher events
            Pusherer::trigger('project_'.$item->project_id, 'item:created', $item, $item->socketId);

            Log::info("ITEM CREATE CALLBACK STARTED");
            // fire off notifications and activity feeds
            Event::subscribe( new ProjectEventHandler );
            Event::fire('item.create', $item);
            // Event::forget('item.created');
            Log::info("ITEM CREATE CALLBACK FINISHED");
        });
}
}
```

Why would it aggrege my events each time I save something?

Comment: why you are firing the event here again?:

`Event::fire('project.create', array($project));

 Event::fire('project.create', array($project));`

Comment: Embarrasing! Thanks, that has solved my project event being fire multiple times, not any of my other models.

Comment: See on the other models if you have called more than once.

Comment: Certainly not the case, for example in my item class, I just call, `Event::fire('item.created', $item);` then `Event::forget('item.created');`

Comment: Seems good. In any where, can you check in case the event is fired?